# Atualizar tabela sem perder informação

Tags: php, imagem, sql-update

Estou fazendo uma tela de perfil com foto. O *upload* e *display* dela está ok. Porém quando altero algum outro dado da página e salvo, a imagem é deletada do banco (ou pelo menos some do banco). Como posso alterar dados nesta tela sem perder a imagem de perfil atual?

View da tela:

```
<?php foreach($info as $info): ?>

<div class="form-group">
        <img src="assets/images/perfil/<?php echo $info['foto']; ?>" border="1" class="perfil_pic" /><br />
        <input type="file" name="foto" class="btn btn-default add_file" style="float:left;"/>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

Controller da tela:

$u = new Usuarios();

if(isset($_POST['nome']) && !empty($_POST['nome'])){
      $img = $_FILES['foto'];
      $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
      $senha = base64_encode($_POST['senha']);
      $nome = addslashes($_POST['nome']);
      $sobrenome = addslashes($_POST['sobrenome']);
            $aniversario = addslashes($_POST['aniversario']);
            $bio = addslashes($_POST['bio']);

      $u->updatePerfil($img, $email, $senha, $nome, $sobrenome, $aniversario, $bio);
```

Model da tela:

```
public function updatePerfil($pic, $email, $senha, $nome, $sobrenome, $aniversario, $bio){
            $id = $_SESSION['fkr'];
            $url = '';
            if (count($pic) > 0) {
                $tipos = array('image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/png');
                if (in_array($pic['type'], $tipos)) {
                    $url = 'perfilatual';
                    switch($pic['type']){
                        case 'image/jpeg':
                        case 'image/jpg':
                            $url .= '.jpg';
                            break;
                        case 'image/png':
                            $url .= '.jpg';
                            break;
                }
            }
             move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], 'assets/images/perfil/' . $url);
         }
            $sql = "UPDATE usuarios SET foto = '$url', senha = '$senha', email = '$email', nome = '$nome', sobrenome = '$sobrenome', aniversario = '$aniversario', bio = '$bio' WHERE id = '$id'";
            $this->db->query($sql);
        }
```

Comment: Está utilizando algum framerwork?

Outra coisa, tente colocar teu código dentro da tag <code></code> para facilitar a visualização no forum!

Comment: Olá, valeu pela dica sobre a tag. O projeto é em MVC.

Comment: Se fosse eu... No teu caso eu não salvaria a url da imagem no banco de dados.
Faria simplesmente o upload da imagem, nomeando a imagem como o ID do usuário.

Comment: Você provavelmente não está verificando se a imagem que vem da requisição é nula e está substituindo a já existente por uma nula.

Comment: E como verifico?

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
public function adicionar() {
$data['nome'] = $this->input->post('nome');

if ($this->Usuarios_model->adicionar('usuarios', $data)) {
        $id_usuarios = $this->db->insert_id();

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'upload/imagens_usuarios/' . $id_usuarios . '.jpg');            

        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Usuário Adicionado');
        redirect('admin/usuarios/index', 'refresh');
    }

}

public function editar()
{

$data['nome'] = $this->input->post('nome');
if ($this->Usuarios_model->editar('usuarios', $data, 'id', $this->input->post('id')) == TRUE) {

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'upload/imagens_usuarios/' . $this->input->post('id') . '.jpg');

$this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Usuário Editado');         
redirect('admin/usuarios/index', 'refresh');

}

}
```

Coloque este código no te model:

```
    //IMAGE URL//
function get_image_url($type = '', $id = '') {
    if (file_exists('upload/imagens_usuarios' . '/' . $id . '.jpg'))
        $image_url = base_url() . 'upload/imagens_usuarios' . '/' . $id .  '.jpg';
    else
        $image_url = base_url() . 'upload/imagens_usuarios/padrao.jpg';

    return $image_url;
}
```

Utiize este código para carregar a imagem na View

```
<input class="file-input" type="file" onchange="preview(this)" name="userfile" style="opacity: 0"/>
<img id="" class="" src="<?php echo $this->Usuarios_model->get_image_url('usuarios');?>" alt="">
```

Comment: Olá, deu certo para mim. O upload aparentemente acontece, mas não atualiza.

Comment: *Não deu certo... quis dizer

Comment: Como assim, o upload aparentemente acontece?
A imagem foi para a pasta ou não?

Comment: Perdão, quis dizer que não houve bug ou erro, mas o upload não acontece. Lembrando que ainda sou noob em PHP... rsrss

Comment: O bizarro é que as outras informações deste perfil (nome, sobrenome, etc), mesmo se não forem alteradas permanecem normal. Somente a imagem que se não for upada de novo some.

Comment: Post aqui, a função que está usando para adicionar imagem e fazer o upload, por favor!

Comment: Some, pois como foi dito pelo Danilo, Você não está verificando se a imagem que vem da requisição é nula e está substituindo a já existente por uma nula.
Para a imagem você deveria ter algo como `if (!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])):`

Comment: Faço assim?<code></code>

Comment: Faço assim? <code>if (isset($_FILES['foto']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['foto']['name'])) {
        $img = $_FILES['foto'];
      }</code>

Comment: Coloquei assim if (isset($_FILES['foto']) && !empty($_FILES['foto'])) {
        $img = $_FILES['foto'];
      } e upload está ok, porém o problema de update permanece. O que deveria ir no else?